# Centralisers of involutions not quasi-isolated

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, centralisers

The quasi-isolated elements of the algebraic group $G=\operatorname{PGL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ are classified in the paper "quasi-isolated elements in reductive groups" by C. Bonnafe.

Let's focus on the involutions of $G$. I'm interested in the centralisers $C$ in $G$ of the elementary abelian 2-subgroups generated by involutions. If none of the generators is quasi-isolated, will $C$ always be connected? Direct computation for small $n$ shows it is true. Has this been studied somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: Definition (from Bonnafé's abstract) "A semisimple element $s$ of a connected reductive group $G$ is said *quasi-isolated* (respectively *isolated*) if $C_G(s)$ (respectively $C^0_G(s)$) is not contained in a Levi subgroup of a proper parabolic subgroup of $G$."

Comment: Yes and the information on $C/C^{\circ}$ is also provided by Table 2, I believe.